# How can I see files in public_html on my Godaddy hosting?

Tags: html, ftp, hosting, public-html

I bought a hosting without domain name from Godaddy. I added some files in public_html directory using FTP and godaddy online file manager. I have an ip address to reach that hosting, lets name it 111.111.11.1. I should be able to see my files when i open 111.111.11.1/filename.php. When i try it, a "file not found" error appears, although "Preview Website" function which is in the cpanel shows correct files. How can i set it?

Answer (score 0):

You are right regarding the preview part, it works because godaddy executes the files and pushes it to your client from its IP which allows incoming connection (Since IP is known, no issues of DNS).

The reason why it does not work with the IP you allotted is because of DNS.  For your browser to know what the host (IP in your case) points to, it looks up at DNS of your ISP, or Google DNS (8.8.8.8).  It does not find any entry matching your IP, hence you are not forwarded.

**Solution**
You would need to buy a domain.  Then set up your hosting IP to that domain.  Then when you enter the domain name - your client will lookup DNS, will resolve the IP, then it will go to your hosting page and render your site.